# How can I display NULL values in formatted datetimeoffset column?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

SSRS - Report Builder 3.0

We have recently migrated all our SQL Server datetime columns to datetimeoffset columns.  This has had a deleterious effect on one of our reports.

The report references a NULLABLE datetimeoffset column called TerminalStateDateTime.  I wish to use the following formatting:

= Format(Fields!TerminalStateDateTime.Value.DateTime, "dd MMM yyyy hh:mm")

Unfortunately, when the value of TerminalStateDateTime is NULL, it shows #Error.  I've tried using IIF and Switch to trap this, but nothing works:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!TerminalStateDateTime.Value), "", Format(Fields!TerminalStateDateTime.Value.DateTime, "dd MMM yyyy hh:mm"))
```

[image]

Does anyone have any idea how to disregard NULL values and yet correctly format non-NULL values?

Thanks

Edward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your easiest option is to simply apply the formatting at the Textbox, not via an expression.

With some simple data:

```
select TerminalStateDateTime = cast('20140101' as datetimeoffset)
union all select TerminalStateDateTime = cast('20140201' as datetimeoffset)
union all select null
```

[image]

I have a simple table:

[image]

The first column simply displays the value. The second uses your expression, i.e.

```
= Format(Fields!TerminalStateDateTime.Value.DateTime, "dd MMM yyyy hh:mm")
```

The third applies the same format, but in the textbox properties:

[image]

You can see this doesn't give `#Error`:

[image]